# any way to get the students to graph functions by hand?

Tags: discussion

I just answered yet another question  [How to solve ${x^5-3x^3+2x^2-2>0}$ without using a graphing calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113628/how-to-solve-x5-3x32x2-20-without-using-a-graphing-calculator/2113814#2113814)   in which the OP is unable to draw a graph by hand. As usual, I gave a site where one may download pdfs of graph paper (also called quadrille paper), then print those out, producing (wait for it) graph paper!

This is just one question of many. We learn to visualize by drawing things ourselves. We are Homo Faber, [Man the Maker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_faber). We have hands, using them is integral to understanding.  [Here is a blog on this general idea](http://wisdomofhands.blogspot.com/2011/02/way-to-brain.html) Also, [Maria Montessori said so](http://www.villadimaria.org/blog/2016/2/24/the-hands-are-the-instruments-of-mans-intelligence-dr-maria-montessori). She wouldn't lie.

Comment: Drawing (mathematical) things by hand is apparently a dying art. Maybe it's the teachers who should be asked about this and not the students...

Comment: This may be more suited for Mathematics Educators (http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)